# Why IgniteClient doesnot support atomic sequence?

Tags: java, ignite, thin-client

I am setting up JavathinClient. Need to understand how can i get hold of atomic sequence? 
    getAtomicSeq()
is accessible through ignite instance but not with IgniteClient.

```
private void init(IgniteClient client, String tableName) {
    ClientCache superCache = defForClient.getSuperCache()
```

> there is no API such as atomic sequence in the IgniteClient class. so how do i acheive something like :

```
    IgniteAtomicSequence seq = client.atomicSequence(tableName, 0, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point, thin clients don't support Atomics and DataStructures functionality. Probably this support will be added in the future. As for now, you can use Thick client, which supports all Ignite APIs: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers#section-configuring-clients-and-servers

Comment: Hi,Thankyou . We have implemented thick client already was trying thinClient  for some specifics. Any idea in which version ignite might release these functionality.

Comment: There are no concrete plans to implement this at the moment. So please don't rely on it getting available.